# Optimize MySQL join query to remove Using temporary and use an index?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, indexing

I have a query with `ORDER BY name` and the index on `name` is being ignored.

How can I optimize the query to use an index and get rid of `Using temporary` from EXPLAIN?

I have `log-queries-not-using-indexes` enabled and I'm seeing this query thousands of times.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT l.parent_id, j.id, j.location_id, j.currency, j.frequency, ROUND((j.salary_min + j.salary_max)/2) as salary 
FROM jobs AS j
JOIN location AS l
    ON j.location_id = l.id
WHERE j.salary_min !=0 
    AND j.status != 'Rejected'      
    AND l.published =1
    AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) <= j.effected_date
ORDER BY l.name
```

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                    | key           | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | j     | range  | effected_date,location_id,status | effected_date | 9       | NULL                       |  562 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY       | 4       | esljw_joomla.j.location_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary_min` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary_max` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effected_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `effected_date` (`effected_date`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10130 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=304 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `published + id` composite index to `location` table
2. Move `l.published =1` condition to the `ON` clause

This is what you can to do in your case. But probbaly you'll never get rid of `using temporary` since you're sorting not by primary table, but by joined table.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by moving the l.published=1 to the ON clause?

Comment: @David Rogers: `ON j.location_id = l.id AND l.published=1`

Comment: Hmm... I tried `alter table location add index id_pub (id, published)` and `alter table location add index pub_id (published, id)`.  EXPLAIN still chooses the primary `j.id` index and doesn't use the new indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've listed `job` first. Change the order of the tables, like this:

```
SELECT l.parent_id, j.id, j.location_id, j.currency, j.frequency, ROUND((j.salary_min + j.salary_max)/2) as salary 
FROM location AS l
JOIN jobs AS j  ON j.location_id = l.id
WHERE j.salary_min !=0 
AND j.status != 'Rejected'      
AND l.published =1
AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) <= j.effected_date
ORDER BY l.name
```

Try it and post how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already.  It still gives the same explain output.   Thanks though!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Many times I've done queries where you have proper primary table as first in query, with good indexes, adding STRAIGHT_JOIN alone can fix a query.  So, with your existing criteria, you should be good with your date index and use that as the primary criteria...  such as

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      L.Parent_ID, 
      J.id, 
      J.location_id, 
      J.currency, 
      J.frequency, 
      ROUND(( J.salary_min + J.salary_max) / 2 ) as Salary 
   FROM
      jobs J
         join Location L
            on J.Location_ID = L.ID
            AND L.Published = 1
   WHERE
          J.Effected_Date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
      AND J.salary_min != 0
      AND J.status != 'Rejected'
   ORDER BY 
      L.name
```

Comment: Ha, I never even heard of STRAIGHT_JOIN, I'm going to have to research that.  =)  The query works great but EXPLAIN still shows `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`